# Error ORA-01841: when passing date of birth in a file

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-loader, oracle12c

I am passing "19851003" as date of birth in a file but i am getting the following error in the log file.

```
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
```

Any idea why is the error coming as i am passing it as a string only

Error in Log File :

```
error processing column DATE_OF_BIRTH in row 2 for datafile /xfer/x/directory/filename.csv
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
```

My table code:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  ID                  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),      
  FIRST_NAME          VARCHAR2(150 BYTE),
  LAST_NAME           VARCHAR2(150 BYTE),
  MIDDLE_NAME         VARCHAR2(150 BYTE),
  DATE_OF_BIRTH       DATE
)

ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY DIRECTORY_TABLES
  ACCESS PARAMETERS 
  (RECORDS  DELIMITED BY '\n'
   SKIP 1
   BADFILE  DIRECTORY_TABLES:'filelist.bad'
   LOGFILE  DIRECTORY_TABLES:'filelist.log'
   DISCARDFILE   DIRECTORY_TABLES:'filelist.dsc'
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
   MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
   REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS
   (ID                  ,
    FIRST_NAME          ,
    LAST_NAME           ,
    MIDDLE_NAME         ,
    DATE_OF_BIRTH       DATE "YYYYMMDD" 
   )
)
LOCATION (DIRECTORY_TABLES:'filename.csv')
)
REJECT LIMIT 0
NOPARALLEL
NOMONITORING;
```

MY CSV File :

```
"id","First Name","Last Name","MI","DOB"
"2","Felicia","Brown","M","19810209"
"3","Jose","Romero","M","19890706"
"4","Valerie","Moore","","19621112"
```

Comment: Is the table expecting a date data type for that particular column?

Comment: please see the edit. i hv added my code

Comment: Any chance of bad data in your `filename.csv`?

Comment: i checked.... it is giving this error when i am quering the table... which means there some problem with the date

Comment: I'm guessing that you want the last character of the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` line to be an apostrophe, but it's something else - look at the automatic syntax highlighting above - it's rather messed up. Try changing that last character to be a proper apostrophe. (This may just have been mis-formatted when posting it here, but maybe not... :-). Share and enjoy.

Comment: field termitaed by is , and not apostrophe @bob jarvis

Comment: @user3809240 - that isn't what Bob meant. Look at `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',’` - the last character is `’` instead of `'`. That looks like a smart-quotes issue. You also seem to have a `}` later on. Can you also show the first few lines of the CSV file?

Comment: added.. please check @AlexPoole and the aposthophe and } is just and copy paste issue. i corrected it

Answer (score 2):

In the spec for DATE_OF_BIRTH a date-format-spec is required. Try:

```
DATE_OF_BIRTH  CHAR DATE_FORMAT DATE MASK "YYYYMMDD"
```

[Reference here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/et_params.htm#i1009548) and then search for "date_format_spec"

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

19851003 is not between -4713 and 9999 just like the error says.

I suspect you want to pass 1985 as the year and you are accidentally passing a full date (yyyyMmdd)

Comment: no i am passing a date... whose format is YYYYMMDD this is what i have wrriten while creating the table as well

Comment: What data type is your stored procedure or table expecting? Your question says "passing a year" but your comment says date. Please can you clarify?

Comment: Can you post the bad file and log - answer to this is not obvious from the info posted. Also, can you try specifying delimiter as NEWLINE instead of '\n'?

Comment: Did you try changing the "'\n'" to "NEWLINE"? can you post the following: sed 's/[A-Za-z]/x/g' filename.csv | head -2 | od -c . This will hide the names, but show the data file and its format.